# Magento Conceptual Schema

Tags: class, magento, schema, uml, diagram

Had been looking at overall architecture to understand Magento system.
-- Design Principle and Pattern used in Magento( Was able to find some blogs) and
-- UML diagrams of Magento Architecture( Didn't find anything).

For UML related point Was searching for 
1) Magento Conceptual Schema.

Class Diagram, Activity Diagram, Use case Diagram or any any suggested UML diagram that gives in-depth understanding of Magento Architecture.

For example : I want to understand how FPC container are linked to block content.
It would be helpful if there was some model diagram showing the effect and relationship.
Or
If you look at shipping code complete $request model is passed.
So have a class diagram and some additional model diagram will html understand whether one should modify request while passing for shipping or modify each shipping module to get expected result.

Over all My idea is that of having Model diagrams that gives an insight as to how magento code flow works and if a developer wants to follow magento standards how he should proceed.

Answer (score 1):

> Had been looking at overall architecture
>   Didn't find anything

There is plenty of documentation. For example, have a look at this book: ISBN-13: 978-1782163060

So without us knowing what are you aiming at, there will be no reasonable hint to be given.

> Was searching for 1) Magento Conceptual Schema.

What about "Magento Architecture"? "Magento UML"? "Magento Patterns"? :)
For example, have a look:
[Magento Design Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041473/magento-design-patterns)

> Class Diagram, Activity Diagram, Use case Diagram or any any suggested UML diagram that gives in-depth understanding of Magento Architecture.

I do not see how those relate to the overall architecture since they tend to focus on certain aspects or to be overly general.

Comment: Have added certain points to My post as per your comments so as to clarify My objective.